# Laravel delete query returns 0 affected rows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am wanting to check if rows were affected after a delete statement in Laravel.

My code:

```
private function removeUserOutstandingRecord()
{
    $query = UserOutstanding::where('o_id', $this->outstanding_id)->delete();

    dd($query);

    if(!$query) {
        Log::error('Could not delete user outstanding record. Outstanding ID given: ' . $this->outstanding_id);
        throw new \Exception('Oops.');
    }

    return true;
}
```

The die & dump returns `0` even though a record has been removed.

Comment: I would do something a bit different. Assign this user to a variable: `$user = UserOutstanding::where("o_id", "=", $this->outstanding_id)->first();` Then call `if($user->delete()) { // user was deleted } else { // user was not deleted }`. See if that works for you.

Comment: Somehow, it's still returning 0!

Comment: Nvm, so the record has been deleted? Hmm. So maybe `->delete()` doesn't return the count of the rows deleted? I'm not entirely sure, I've never run a `dd()` on a `delete()` call.

Comment: Sorry, it's a friday. One of those mistakes. I was deleting a record before the `removeUserOutstandingRecord()` method was hit. Turns out o_id is a FK and `cascades` on delete so the method hit before `removeUserOutstandingRecord()` was actually deleting the record.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Glad you got it sorted out!